# RegEx works when tested but not in .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this regular expression that works perfectly when I test it in RegExr (http://regexr.com?36ms0), however when I add it to my .htaccess it never matches.

RegEx:

```
^(?!.*\.(?:(?:ht|x)ml|j(?:peg|s|pg)|p(?:hp|ng)|[rc]ss|bmp|ico|gif)$).*$
```

This regex should match strings like "testphp" and "test.rar" but not "test.php" or any of the other included extensions.

.htaccess in subdomain

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    # handle YouTube token
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^login/ login/%1/? [NE,R=301,L]

    # add trailing slash for the looks
    RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

    # html5 pushstate (history) support:
    # we do want to give error pages for certain file types though.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^(?!.*?\.((ht|x)ml|j(peg|s|pg)|p(hp|ng)|[rc]ss|bmp|ico|gif)$).*?$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) / [L]
</ifModule>
```

Purpose of this .htaccess file is to redirect any request to the index, apart from any file ending in .php, .html, .css, jpg, ... and any file or directory that exists. Browsing to `http://mysite.com/test/` would redirect to the index. Browsing to `http://mysite.com/test.php` would show the file or a 404 if it doesn't exist. Browsing to `http://mysite.com/test.rar` would download the file or redirect to the index if it doesn't exist.

I have another .htaccess in my server root:

```
SetEnv PHPRC /home/ttrcusto/public_html/cgi-bin/php.ini

<Files ~ "\.(ini)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

Redirect /unsubscribe http://ttrcustoms.us/#account=edit
Redirect /cydia http://repo.ttrcustoms.us
Redirect /Cydia http://repo.ttrcustoms.us
Redirect /repo http://repo.ttrcustoms.us
Redirect /tools http://tools.ttrcustoms.us

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^repo/deb/(.*)\.deb$ /download.php?package=$1.deb [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the regex and your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|ico|css|rss|js|html?|xml|php)$ / [L,NC]
```

Comment: This isn't the same regex, it does a different thing.

Comment: Can you please elaborate `it does a different thing` ?

Comment: Just edited my question to do just that :p this regex would match test.php, while it should not match test.php and should match strings like test.rar and testphp

Comment: /cheese.php should give a 404 since it's an url ending in .php and the file doesn't exist.

Comment: Using just the above rules `/cheese.php` does give 404. Do you have any other code in your `.htaccess` clashing with above rule?

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^token=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^login/ login/%1/? [NE,R=301,L]
and
RewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]

Neither of those should conflict.

Comment: So what happens when you open `/cheese.php` ?

Comment: It loads the index page

Comment: That shouldn't happen for 2 reasons: 1) `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and 2) `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` rule. btw your 2nd rule isn't even needed since it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Stepping away for a meeting. WIll be back in an hour. Please leave your comments and I will respond.

Comment: The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` would prevent the server from redirecting to test.rar if the file exists. the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}` rule would redirect test.rar to index if it doesnt exists. That same rule would prevent test.php from being redirected to the index even if it doesn't exist. Both rules are needed.

Comment: That's right bot are needed and I wasn't questioning that. I was suggesting that because of presence of those 2 RewriteCond your URI `/cheese.php` wouldn't be rewritten to `/` (and indeed in my testing it doesn't). Do you have `ErrorDocument` lines present there?

Comment: No I don't, it should just give the standard 404

Comment: 3 questions. Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: No, I have another .htaccess in my root. Will update my question with the info you want.

Comment: If that is your root's `.htaccess` then place above rule in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` only.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. Apologies for the late reply, but I've been busy for school

Comment: Ok can you tell me which URL isn't working for you? (Give full URL)

Comment: The url http://yousub.ttrcustoms.us/fail.php should give a 404 error, but instead shows the index.

Comment: And what is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: The first .htaccess file is located in document/root/yousub/ (the root folder of the subdomain), the second .htaccess is located in document/root/

Comment: ok can you place this rule **as first rule** in both the .htaccess files?

Comment: Which rule do you mean? The one you suggested?

Comment: this is weird, Can you try it out a new browser to avoid caching issues.

Comment: I don't understand either, it should work. Trying a new browser didn't help. I even tried this on a different server with only this rule in the only .htaccess and it still doesn't work...

Comment: Ok I made another edit, can you try this edited code n both .htaccess files and retest.

Comment: No, now it just redirects everything the main domain.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39376/discussion-between-anubhava-and-cupoftea696)

Answer (score 0):

Im betting you problem is that whatever is reading your regex doesn't understand perl type regular expressions like `(?!` and `(?:`, but I have no idea what is reading that file.